# Remove string with brackets in R

Tags: string, r

I have a data.frame looks like this:

```
name
Lily(1+2)
John(good+1)
Tom()
Jim
Alice(*+#)
.....
```

I want to remove all brackets and everything inside the brackets in R. What should I do?

I prefer my data.frame can be looked like:

```
name
Lily
John
Tom
Jim
Alice
....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# read your sample data:
d <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE, comment='`')
# remove strings in parentheses
transform(d, name=gsub('\\(.*\\)', '', name))
#    name
# 1  Lily
# 2  John
# 3   Tom
# 4   Jim
# 5 Alice
```